# Python kivy placing buttons/labels in different places using float layout

Tags: kivy, python-3.4

i am new to kivy, until now ive only used tkinter, however i want to create a app for android, so now ive moved to kivy.

i've seen that widgets works totally different in kivy, anyway i simply want to place labels and buttons on a screen, i've done this with other layouts but its said that a float layout is kinda like tkinter's .place()..... so i thought that this might work but unfortunately i just can't seem to find out how to place something at my choice on the screen. Here is the program on which i want to add the buttons and labels:

```
from random import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line
from kivy.core.window import Window


class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        color = (0,0,0)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*color, mode='hsv')
            d = 10
            Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d / 2, touch.y - d / 2), size=(d, d))
            touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y),width=5)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]


class MyPaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        self.painter = MyPaintWidget()
        clearbtn = Button(text='Clear')
        clearbtn.bind(on_release=self.clear_canvas)
        parent.add_widget(self.painter)
        parent.add_widget(clearbtn)
        return parent

    def clear_canvas(self, obj):
        self.painter.canvas.clear()


MyPaintApp().run()
```

this creates a drawing screen, what i want is a sort of simulated 'contract' on which the user can sighn, but i can't figure out how to place the buttons and labels at my choice.

Comment: Your example does not use `FloatLayout`. Have you looked at [the documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.floatlayout.html) and played with the examples?

Comment: i did not use the layout because ive been to the documentation and it did not describe how to use a .place()

Comment: oh sorry, ive just seen that u use, pos = ()

Comment: is it possible to use a float layout on a Widget?

Comment: a `FloatLayout` **is** a `Widget`. Consult [Widgets and Layouts](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/widgets.html#organize-with-layouts) as a start...

Comment: thanks, il check it up, will you write a answer so i can mark it as answered?

Comment: thanks alot zeeMonkeez your comment answered my question if you will be so kind as to sent it as a answer i will mark it as right

Comment: oh im sorry, now i can place the buttons and labels to my choice but i still have a dificuilt time to adjust the size of our floatlayout, do you by any chance know how to do that? something like the root.geometry of tkinter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this question was already answered by zeeMonkeez:

Your example does not use FloatLayout. Have you looked at the documentation and played with the examples?

so for anybody who have the same problem heres the answer:

```
from random import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        color = (0,0,0)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*color, mode='hsv')
            d = 3
            Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d / 2, touch.y - d / 2), size=(d, d))
            touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y),width=1.5)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]


class MyPaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        parent = FloatLayout()
        self.painter = MyPaintWidget()
        a_button = Button(text = 'A button',pos=(20,20),size_hint=(.25,.25))
        entry_name = TextInput()
        parent.add_widget(self.painter)
        parent.add_widget(a_button)
        return parent

    def clear_canvas(self, obj):
        self.painter.canvas.clear()


MyPaintApp().run()
```